# How to install ImageMagick in Mac for simple task (R)

Tags: macos, imagemagick, gif

I have a simple task I want to carry out and after exhausting all resources on google I'm stumped. I think whats hindering me most is installing ImageMagick. When I used my terminal I get errors. All I want to do is make some plots on R and make a GIF out of them. Is there anyone way to confirm ImageMagick is installed?

Comment: what version OS are you running?

Comment: 10.8.5 please help im going mad.

Comment: Mind sharing the errors you get in terminal when trying to get Image Magick working?

Comment: -bash: port: command not found

Comment: Sorry when I type port install imagemagick I get -bash: port: command not found

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly thank god for you and homebrew!

Comment: Great--yes, the homebrew/port systems can be messy sometimes. All for the love of gifs, of course.

Answer (score 3):

In general you will need either MacPorts or Homebrew installed first to install ImageMagick. As you stated above it sounds like you don't have Macports installed.

If you don't have either installed, I'm a big fan of homebrew, and so I'll walk your through install with homebrew.

**Step 1**. First install homebrew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install)"
```

as per the homebrew website [here](http://brew.sh/).

Once that's done installing you'll then be able to use commands like `brew install foo` where foo is something you'd like to install. In your example you see `port install imagemagick` which is the Macports way of installing image magick.

**Step 2**. Install imagemagick. As per ImageMagick Mountain Lion instructions [here](http://sethvargo.com/20110726/install-imagemagick-on-mountain-lion/):

```
brew install imagemagick
```

That command should install imagemagick. A super handy tool with homebrew is `brew doctor` which analyses all the installs you've done with homebrew to make sure they'll properly setup.